# Should libraries be shipped as typescript files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, node-modules

I am using a Postgres client as a dependency in my simple node js server. I noticed that this dependency has built and published itself as `.ts` files, instead of `.js` files. Is that a norm/good-practice? I've usually seen libraries being packages as vanilla js files and (optionally) declaring their types in `.d.ts` files.
Currently, I have to use `allowTsInNodeModules` in my webpack.config.ts to use this dependency, and I get the following error without using this flag:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/pgeon/postgres-client.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: TypeScript emitted no output for /home/dinika/src/expenses-server-node/node_modules/pgeon/postgres-client.ts. By default, ts-loader will not compile .ts files in node_modules.
You should not need to recompile .ts files there, but if you really want to, use the allowTsInNodeModules option.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a best practice nor the norm. The developer of that library should likely read [how to publish TypeScript packages](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html).

A summary is they should have a `main` and `types` key in their `package.json` and be [compiling their TypeScript to declarations and JavaScript (`*.d.ts` and `*.js` files)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#declaration).